# Pasar variable de PHP a jQuery desde diferentes archivos

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

Buenas tardes. Escribo después de leer todos los casos parecidos relacionados con mi consulta en este foro y no encontrar solución.

Lo que necesito saber es si se puede pasar la variable de un documento PHP al código jQuery escrito en otro documento.

Ejemplo del código:

**Archivo con nombre "pre_modificar.php" (HTML con JAVASCRIPT)**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Paso previo a modificar</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter/jquery-latest.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $("#modificar").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                         
      var consulta;
             
      $("#id").focus();
                                                 
      $("#id").keyup(function(e){
             consulta = $("#id").val();
                                      
             //hace la búsqueda
             $("#resultado").delay(100).queue(function(n) {      
                                           
                  $("#resultado").html('<img src="imagenes/loading/ajax-loader.gif" />');
                                           
                  $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "comprobar.php",
                       data: "b="+consulta,
                       dataType: "html",
                       error: function(){
                       alert("Error petición ajax");
                       },
                       success: function(data){        
                                    
if (VARIABLE_PHP_QUE_NO_SE_COMO_OBTENER == 0) {
$("#resultado").html(data);
n();
} else {           
$("#modificar").removeAttr('disabled');
$("#resultado").html(data);
n();
}
}

});
});                                   
});                             
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
 
 <form name="seleccionar" action="modificar.php" method="post">
        <input type="int" required id="id" name="id" placeholder="Introduce ID..." value="" />
  <span id="resultado"></span>  
        <input type="submit" id="modificar" name="modificar" value="Modificar" /><br><br/>  
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

He escrito como **VARIABLE_PHP_QUE_NO_SE_COMO_OBTENER** la variable que debería obtener del documento PHP que a continuación detallo.

**Archivo con nombre "comprobar.php" (PHP)**

```html
<?php
      $user = $_POST['b'];
       
      if(!empty($user)) {
            comprobar($user);
      }
       
      function comprobar($b) {
   
   include("conexion_db.php");
   
   $query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM formulario WHERE id = '".$b."'");        
   
            $contar = mysqli_num_rows($query);
             

            if($contar == 0){
                  echo "<span><img src=\"imagenes\web\action_delete.png\"></span>"; 
      
            }else{
                  echo "<span><img src=\"imagenes\web\action_check.png\"></span>";
            }
      }     
?>
```

La variable que quiero pasar de este documento PHP al primer documento donde esta el código jQuery es: **$contar**

¿Podrían indicarme si hay solución posible para resolver este caso?

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: pues si ya lo tienes en : `success: function(data)`  en la variable **data**, ahí esta tu resultado, solo te falta enviar el dato de **php** con un `return json_encode($contar)` y ya tienes todo.

Answer (score 2):

Retorna un objeto json con el html que deseas mostrar y el contador. Para eso puedes utilizar la clase `stdClass`:

```
function comprobar($b) {

            include("conexion_db.php");

            $query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM formulario WHERE id = '".$b."'");        

            $contar = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            $response = new stdClass();
            $response->contador = $contar;

            if($contar == 0){
                  $response->img = "<span><img src=\"imagenes\web\action_delete.png\"></span>"; 

            }else{
                  $response->img ="<span><img src=\"imagenes\web\action_check.png\"></span>";
            }

          echo json_encode($response);
      }
```

Entonces en el response del ajax tendras 2 propiedaes que serian `contador` y `html` que puedes utilizar para realizar lo que quieres:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "comprobar.php",
    data: "b="+consulta,
    dataType: "html",
    error: function(){
        alert("Error petición ajax");
    },
    success: function(data){                    

        if (data.contador == 0) {
            $("#resultado").html(data.html);
            n();
        } else {                                        
            $("#modificar").removeAttr('disabled');
            $("#resultado").html(data);
            n();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Mira mi respuesta actualizada.